# Change the id of button id on clone jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dom

```
<div id="del2">
<textarea placeholder="School" class="form-control input-lg" name="message2" id="message2" rows="1" cols="30">School</textarea>
 <button id="delete1" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Delete this Widget</button></div>
```

code

```
$("#"+divid) .clone().attr('id', 'del'+ value).insertAfter($("#"+divid)).find('textarea').attr('name', 'message'+ value).attr('id', 'message'+ value).find("button").button().attr('id', 'delete'+value);
```

I am able to change the id of div and textarea on clone but the **issue is that i cant change the id of button id**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you are trying to find `<button>` in the `<textarea>` element. I have indented your code to make it a little more readable:

```
$("#"+divid) 
.clone()
.attr('id', 'del'+ value)
.insertAfter($("#"+divid))
.find('textarea')
    .attr('name', 'message'+ value)
    .attr('id', 'message'+ value)
    .find("button")  // Problem is here - you are finding <button> in <textarea>
        .button()
        .attr('id', 'delete'+value);
```

Try using `.end()` (see [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/end/)) after you're done working with an element fetched using `.find()`, in order to return the previous selected object. Also, you can actually combine the two `.attr()` methods by using objects:

```
$('#'+divid) 
.clone()
.attr('id', 'del'+ value)
.insertAfter($('#'+divid))
.find('textarea')
    .attr({
        'name': 'message'+ value,
        'id': 'message'+ value
     })
    .end() // Forces return to previously matched elements, i.e. the cloned element
.find('button')
    .button()
    .attr('id', 'delete'+value);
```